# C# Color Detection more than one result

Tags: c#, color-detection

i've a question about color detection. i've code but i want more than one result. The code is famous but I want to the program to bring me all the results not just one result. I hope I made myself clear.

**My bad I made the missing copy**

```
private Boolean FindBitmap(Bitmap bmpNeedle, Bitmap bmpHaystack, out Point location)
        {
            try
            {

                for (int outerX = 0; outerX < bmpHaystack.Width - bmpNeedle.Width; outerX++)
                {
                    for (int outerY = 0; outerY < bmpHaystack.Height - bmpNeedle.Height; outerY++)
                    {
                        for (int innerX = 0; innerX < bmpNeedle.Width; innerX++)
                        {
                            for (int innerY = 0; innerY < bmpNeedle.Height; innerY++)
                            {
                                Color cNeedle = bmpNeedle.GetPixel(innerX, innerY);
                                Color cHaystack = bmpHaystack.GetPixel(innerX + outerX, innerY + outerY);

                                if (cNeedle.R != cHaystack.R || cNeedle.G != cHaystack.G || cNeedle.B != cHaystack.B)
                                {
                                    goto notFound;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        location = new Point(outerX, outerY);
                        listBox1.Items.Add(location);
                        MessageBox.Show(location.ToString());
                        notFound:
                        continue;
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
            location = Point.Empty;
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: _"The code is famous "_?  What do you mean by that?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gEgxZrXPnzc

Comment: Youtube fame is not real fame. For code it's not even stackoverflow.com fame, and that's not real fame either.

Comment: That fact that the code uses `goto` makes the code _infamous_ in my opinion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to the program to bring me all the results not just one result

Return a List of all results. So you would modify your method to have a different return type:

```
public List<Point> FindBitmap(Bitmap bmpNeedle, Bitmap bmpHaystack, out Point location)
{
    List<Point> results = new List<Point>();

    for (int outerX = 0; outerX < bmpHaystack.Width - bmpNeedle.Width; outerX++)
    {
        for (int outerY = 0; outerY < bmpHaystack.Height - bmpNeedle.Height; outerY++)
        {
            for (int innerX = 0; innerX < bmpNeedle.Width; innerX++)
            {
                for (int innerY = 0; innerY < bmpNeedle.Height; innerY++)
                {
                    Color cNeedle = bmpNeedle.GetPixel(innerX, innerY);
                    Color cHaystack = bmpHaystack.GetPixel(innerX + outerX, innerY + outerY);
                    if (cNeedle.R != cHaystack.R || cNeedle.G != cHaystack.G || cNeedle.B != cHaystack.B)
                    {
                        goto notFound;
                    }
                }
            }
            location = new Point(outerX, outerY);
            // collect the result
            results.Add(location);
            notFound:
            continue;
        }
    }

    // when you are finished looping return it
    return results;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a List before your loop and add each result.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add each found pixel to a collection of pixels. This could be done like:

```
private IEnumerable<Point> FindNeedlePixels()
{
    for (int outerX = 0; outerX < bmpHaystack.Width - bmpNeedle.Width; outerX++)
    {
        for (int outerY = 0; outerY < bmpHaystack.Height - bmpNeedle.Height; outerY++)
        {
            for (int innerX = 0; innerX < bmpNeedle.Width; innerX++)
            {
                for (int innerY = 0; innerY < bmpNeedle.Height; innerY++)
                {
                    Color cNeedle = bmpNeedle.GetPixel(innerX, innerY);
                    Color cHaystack = bmpHaystack.GetPixel(innerX + outerX, innerY + outerY);
                    if (cNeedle.R != cHaystack.R || cNeedle.G != cHaystack.G || cNeedle.B != cHaystack.B)
                    {
                        goto notFound;
                    }
                }
            }
            yield return new Point(outerX, outerY);
            notFound:
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```